# Calculate the processing time per executors on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

As I am experimenting with a possible partition skew in Apache Spark clusters, I need to know the running time of the task processing time per executors.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you need the execution time per Task? Spark UI presents you with the execution time of each Stage

Comment: use spark history UI ?

Comment: Yes. It should answer your problem in addition to other stats

Comment: No, it is not the total time execution time per task that I need  but the time of each executor processes.